# php - show png/image in browser works in localhost but not on aws

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using this code to output a file on uuser web browser.

```
header("Content-Type: image/png");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=".$file_name.".png;");
echo file_get_contents('data:image/png;base64,'. $file_content);
```

This works fine in my localhost docker environment, but in EC2 it shows weird chars (like picture below).

[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: changing `inline` to `attachment` it makes the file download and works, but my goal is to show the file in the browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing it like this:

```
<img src='data:image/png;base64,<?php echo base64_encode(file_get_contents($file_name.".png")); ?>'>
```